# Monitoring GPS Coordinates

Tags: c++, gps, bada

I need to monitor GPS Coordinates changes at every 15 min and take action based on that. as per bada developer guide report "only one application allowed to run at a time   if another application try to run first one is closed" .so that how do i monitor GPS coordinates without interruption from other applications. how do i keep my application running at all times

**UPDATE**
bada agent applications
  [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1c8b9c134c.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1c8b9c134c.jpg)

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but are you asking "How do I multitask when multitasking isn't allowed?"??

Comment: we can use multitasking inside user application but not multiple user applications,  bada platform is not limited to single tasking, bada allows multitasking between base applications such as music player, calendar and so on, I need to know is there any possibilities to keep my application running in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to understand that Agent application functionality still not implemented for 3rd party applications, it is reserved for internal use only. And there is no daemon like application functionalities.

We can use multitasking inside user application but not multiple user applications due to single application policy.

Bada platform is not limited to single tasking, bada allows multitasking between base applications such as music player, calendar and so on.

So continuously monitoring GPS coordinates is difficult

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Bada environment is neither designed nor suited for your application. QUoting Samsung: "According to one of the fundamentals of bada development, bada devices do not support daemon (agent) applications. "

Comment: thanks for your response, I have updated my question please check that

Comment: I've re-checked the 3rd-party developer guide, but it doesn't mention "agents".